# How to find intercept coefficients after setting restrictions with linearHypothese

Tags: r, logistic-regression

So I built my logistic regression model using glm(). When I display the summary I get this with values for each variable.

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
```

After I have set a restriction using linearHypotheses but I only get results for chisquared, residuals df, and df. Am I able to see what the coefficients are for the model with the restriction?

```
library(car)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

logitmodel <- glm(x~ratio+x+y, family=binomial(link="logit"))

nullhypothese <- "x=0"
restrictedmodel <- linearHypothesis(logitmodel, nullhypothesis)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. List all non-base R packages you are using.

Comment: While building the model why is the dependent variable `x` also considered as independent variable? 
`glm(x~ratio+x+y, family=binomial(link="logit"))`